# ListView memory leak in Android

Tags: android

I wrote a class that getting images from JSON.It is working bur there is a problem with memory. when i scroll down the application it is leaking in the memory.Here is my codes.

```
package com.nexum.senddata;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

private ListView list;
private MyAdapter adapter;

    private final String parsingUrl = "http://sametdede.com/expo/data.json";
private String tag_coord = "Coord";
private String tag_lat = "Lat";
private String tag_lon = "Lon";// Double
private String tag_image = "Image";
private String tag_InIzmir = "InIzmir";
private String tag_name = "Name";

private ProgressDialog pDialog;

private static int clickedItemPosition = -1;
private final int REQUEST_CODE_DETAIL = 1;

ArrayList<CoordItem> items;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    items = new ArrayList<CoordItem>();
    adapter = new MyAdapter(this, R.layout.list_item, items);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.exampList);
    list.setAdapter(adapter);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    pDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    pDialog.setMessage("Veriler alınıyor...");

    new ListViewLoad().execute();

    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                long id) {
            /*
             * String bulunma = ""; if (items.get(position).inIzmir) {
             * bulunma+="İzmir de bulundu."; }else{
             * bulunma+="İzmir de bulunmadı."; } String
             * s="Name:"+items.get(position).name+"\nInIzmir:"+bulunma;
             * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), s,
             * Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
             */

            clickedItemPosition = position;
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    DetailActivity.class);
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putParcelable(
                    "parcelable_key",
                    new CoordItem(items.get(position).name, items
                            .get(position).img, items.get(position).lat,
                            items.get(position).lon,
                            items.get(position).inIzmir));
            myIntent.putExtras(bundle);
            // Güncelleme olayı burada başlıyor
            // startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_CODE_DETAIL);

            startActivityForResult(myIntent, REQUEST_CODE_DETAIL);

        }

    });

}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_DETAIL && resultCode == RESULT_OK
            && data != null) {
        CoordItem coorditem = new CoordItem(data.getStringExtra("name"),
                items.get(clickedItemPosition).img, Double.parseDouble(data
                        .getStringExtra("lat")), Double.parseDouble(data
                        .getStringExtra("lon")),
                items.get(clickedItemPosition).inIzmir);

        items.set(clickedItemPosition, coorditem);
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guncelleme yapıldı.",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    /*
     * CoordItem coorditem = new CoordItem(data.getStringExtra("name"),
     * items.get(clickedItemPosition).img,
     * Double.parseDouble(data.getStringExtra("lat")),Double.parseDouble(
     * data.getStringExtra("lon")), items.get(clickedItemPosition).inIzmir);
     * 
     * items.set(clickedItemPosition, coorditem);
     * adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
     * Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Guncelleme yapıldı.",
     * Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     */

}

private class ListViewLoad extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {

        String json = getStringFromURL(parsingUrl);
        try {
            final JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray(json);

            for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject c = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject coord = c.getJSONObject(tag_coord);
                double lat = coord.getDouble(tag_lat);
                double lon = coord.getDouble(tag_lon);
                String image = c.getString(tag_image);
                boolean InIzmir = c.getBoolean(tag_InIzmir);
                String name = c.getString(tag_name);

                CoordItem item = new CoordItem(name, image, lat, lon,
                        InIzmir);
                items.add(item);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}

private class MyAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CoordItem> {

    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
            ArrayList<CoordItem> objects) {
        super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

        this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (items != null)
            return items.size();
        else
            return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        ViewHolder viewholder = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            viewholder = new ViewHolder();

            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent,
                    false);
            viewholder.listItemImage = (ImageView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listItemImage);

            viewholder.listItemName = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listItemName);
            viewholder.listItemInIzmir = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listItemInIzmir);
            viewholder.listItemLatitude = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listItemLatitude);
            viewholder.listItemLongitude = (TextView) convertView
                    .findViewById(R.id.listItemLongitude);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
        } else {
            viewholder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        viewholder.listItemName.setText(items.get(position).name);
        if (items.get(position).inIzmir) {
            viewholder.listItemInIzmir.setText("Izmirde.");
        } else {
            viewholder.listItemInIzmir.setText("Izmirde degil.");
        }

        try {
            viewholder.listItemImage
                    .setImageDrawable(getDrawableFromUrl(new URL(items.get(
                            position).getImg())));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return convertView;
    }

    public Drawable getDrawableFromUrl(URL url) {
        try {
            InputStream is = (InputStream) url.getContent();
            Drawable d = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
            return d;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}

/**
 * Burada layoutinflater da kullandığımız layoutun componentlerini
 * yazıyoruz.Bu da bizim list_item.xml imizdir.
 */
static class ViewHolder {
    ImageView listItemImage;
    TextView listItemName, listItemInIzmir, listItemLatitude,
            listItemLongitude;
}

public String getStringFromURL(String url) {

    // Making HTTP request
    String json = "";
    InputStream is = null;
    try {
        // defaultHttpClient
        DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);

        HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
        HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
        is = httpEntity.getContent();

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "UTF-8"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // return JSON String
    return json;

}
```

}

Where can i read and get image for executing faster and not memory leak?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already used a ViewHolder.

Use LazyList or Universal Image Loader

**Lazy List**

Images can be cached to local sd card or phone mmeory. Url is considered the key. If the key is present in sdcard display images from sd card else display image by downloading from server and cache the same to location of your choice. The cache limit can set. You can also choose your own location to cache images. Cache can also be cleared.

Instead of user waiting to download large images and then displaying lazy list loads images on demand. Since images area cached you can display images offline.

https://github.com/thest1/LazyList. Lazy List

In your getview

```
imageLoader.DisplayImage(imageurl, imageview);
```

ImageLoader Display method

```
public void DisplayImage(String url, ImageView imageView) //url and imageview as parameters
{
imageViews.put(imageView, url);
Bitmap bitmap=memoryCache.get(url);   //get image from cache using url as key
if(bitmap!=null)         //if image exists
    imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);  //dispaly iamge
 else   //downlaod image and dispaly. add to cache.
 {
    queuePhoto(url, imageView);
    imageView.setImageResource(stub_id);
 }
 }
```

**Universal Image Loader**

https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader.

Can load images localy or from server.

It is based on Lazy List(works on same principle). But it has lot of other configurations. I would prefer to use Universal Image Loader coz it gives you more configuration options. You can display a error image if downlaod failed. Can display images with rounded corners. Can cache on disc or memory. Can compress image.

In your custom adapter constructor

```
 File cacheDir = StorageUtils.getOwnCacheDirectory(activity context, "your folder");//for caching

// Get singletone instance of ImageLoader
imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
// Create configuration for ImageLoader (all options are optional)
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(a)
// You can pass your own memory cache implementation
.discCache(new UnlimitedDiscCache(cacheDir)) // You can pass your own disc cache implementation
.discCacheFileNameGenerator(new HashCodeFileNameGenerator())
.enableLogging()
.build();
// Initialize ImageLoader with created configuration. Do it once.
 imageLoader.init(config);
 options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
.showStubImage(R.drawable.stub_id)//display stub image untik image is loaded
.cacheInMemory()
.cacheOnDisc()
.displayer(new RoundedBitmapDisplayer(20))
.build();
```

In your getView()

```
 ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
 imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);//provide imageurl, imageview and options.
```

You can configure with other options to suit your needs.

Comment: I am getting the urls from JSON. So how can i initialize ImageLoader according to my codes?

Comment: imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options); if you are using iniversal image loader use the above. pass image urls to your cusotm adapter and supply url like url[position]

Comment: No no. How can I initialize ImageLoader class. It needs some parameters ImageLoader imageloader = new ImageLoader(?); In my codes what can i put there? thanks

Comment: in your adapter constructor.

Comment: 'public MyAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
    ArrayList<CoordItem> objects) {
   super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);

   this.inflater = (LayoutInflater) context
     .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
   
  }   '   here ?

Comment: But I have no ImageLoaderConfiguration object.

Comment: load configuration in your adapter and in getview ImageView image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.imageview); 
 imageLoader.displayImage(imageurl, image,options);

Comment: Ok I solved the problem. Now I must make my own configuration. Can i use the same configuration in the sources?

Comment: yes you can. Depending on your need change the configuration accordingly